# How can I create a DependsOn relation between EC2 and RDS using aws-cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I am currently using the *aws-cdk* (TypeScript) to create a stack that consists of an *EC2* instance and a *RDS* databaseInstance.

The *RDS* instance needs to be setup before the *EC2* instance can be started and userdata will be executed.

The problem I have is, that I could not find a way to define the `DepensOn` (Cloudformation) attribute between the two resources.

The workaround is, that I am using netsted stacks.

The code looks something like this:

```
const instance = new ec2.Instance(this, 'Instance', {...})
const rdsInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'DbInstance', {...})
```

Now I would like to define something like **`instance.dependsOn(rdsInstance)`**.

Did anybody run into the same issue?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The solution here is to use `addDependency()` on the `node`, this will handle all the necessary CloudFormation `DependsOn` for you:

```ts
const instance = new ec2.Instance(this, 'Instance', {...});
const rdsInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'DbInstance', {...});

instance.node.addDependency(rdsInstance);
```

From the JSDoc of `addDependency()`: *Add an ordering dependency on another Construct. All constructs in the dependency's scope will be deployed before any construct in this construct's scope.*

Comment: I also tried this solution deploying both in one stack. This leads to an exception... `aws-cdk/node_modules/constructs/lib/private/dependency.ts:86
      throw new Error(`${instance} does not implement DependableTrait`); Error: [object Object] does not implement DependableTrait
    at Function.get ...node_modules/constructs/lib/private/dependency.ts:86:13)`

Comment: Which version of the CDK are you using? All modules use the same exact version?

Comment: Just double checked: It's version 1.32.2 (build e19e206) and also all dependencies in package.json have this version.

Comment: Just went through the answer again and I oversaw that in `rdsInstance.node.addDependency(instance);` instance did not have the `.node`. So it works like @jogold described. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: also will be able to add multiple dependencies as array to addDependency method?

Comment: @Sanjari you can do `resource.node.addDependency(...otherResources)`

Comment: Isn't the last line of the code block the wrong way around? `rdsInstance.node.addDependency(instance);` looks like it's declaring `instance` as a dependency of `rdsInstance` (I.e. `instance` starts first), whereas the question appears to want `rdsInstance` to be a dependency of `instance` (i.e. `rdsInstance should start first).

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following helps you.

```
const instance = new ec2.Instance(this, 'Instance', { /* ... */ }).getInstance();
const rdsInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'DbInstance', { /* ... */ }).getInstance();

instance.addDependsOn(rdsInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this somehow does not work, because `ec2.Instance` and `rds.DatabaseInstance` do not have the method `getInstance()`. But somehow we would need to get the underlying `CfnRessource` to call `addDependsOn(otherResource)` if I understood correctly [from the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnResource.html).